# Error converting data type varchar to int. get error in create page

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
public string CreateUpdateBankMaster(BankMaster_IVM objBankMaster)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        DALUtility IMSBIDB = new DALUtility();
        string str = "Exec" + " " + Constants.DB_SP_CreateUpdateBankMaster + " " + objBankMaster.BankID + "," + objBankMaster.SocietyID + ",'" + objBankMaster.BankName + "','" + objBankMaster.BankAddress + "','" + objBankMaster.IsPrimaryBank +"' ";

        var obj = IMSBIDB.ReturnValue(str);
        IMSBIDB = null;

        Int32 Return = Convert.ToInt32(obj);

        if (Return == objBankMaster.BankID)
        {
            result = "Cash expense category updated successfully.";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Cash expense category created successfully.";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUpdateBankMaster] 
(
    @BankID Int,
    @BankName nvarchar(100),
    @BankAddress nvarchar(200),
    @SocietyID Int,
    @IsPrimaryBank bit
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@BankID > 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE BankMaster 
        SET BankName = @BankName,
            BankAddress = @BankAddress,
            IsPrimaryBank = @IsPrimaryBank
        WHERE BankID = @BankID;

        SELECT @BankID;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO BankMaster (SocietyID, BankName, BankAddress, IsPrimaryBank)
        VALUES (@SocietyID, @BankName, @BankAddress, @IsPrimaryBank)

        SELECT @@IDENTITY;
    END
END
```

Gives me an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to int.

Comment: So what is your question? And where is your [MRE]?

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to int.

Comment: I don't know exactly where the mistake is..please help me

Comment: your proc is not transaction safe.

Comment: You need to actually ask a question (in the question i.e [edit] even if its as simple as "can someone please help me solve this error". Also we can't see your data, so without a [MRE] we can't really help much as we would like to. Somewhere in your code something is attempting to convert a string to a number and failing... you need to step through your code and find where that is.

Comment: @mitchwheat I'd take issue with nearly everything about this pair of codes! :)

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY` or `IDENT_CURRENT()` to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Can you explain error message ? What is message ? Can you make a Paste/Copy of image with error message ? Can you tag language used ? C# ? Java ? Can you trace/debug your code and explain which data input produce your error ?

Comment: You really want to be using parameters (SqlParameter) as well. And while I don't know the details of your DAL, `ReturnValue` would not normally return a `select` value, it would normally return a `return` value. And what is BankId is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have your parameters in a different order in your C# than in your stored procedure, meaning you're putting an `address` into the `society ID`. An address probably won't convert to an integer and I think it highly likely to be the source of the error. Though other things are misaligned too, such as putting the `societyID` int into the `bankName`, an automatic int-to-string conversion will succeed

Here is a comparison of what your stored procedure expects and what your c# supplies:

```
SP: @BankID, @BankName, @BankAddress, @SocietyID, @IsPrimaryBank
C#: .BankID, .SocietyID, .BankName, .BankAddress, .IsPrimaryBank
```

Change the order of one or the other so they are aligned. There are numerous other issues with your code, but this will probably resolve the error you're seeing

Comment: I can. Changing the order of parameters in a stored procedure/changing the order that variables are concatenate into a string is one of the most basic things you can do as a developer- really "first day of programming 101" stuff. I'm struggling to understand how it came to be that you can write all this complex database access code, and yet not be capable of a simple advice to change the order of these things?